# Angular pipe doesn't display data in an HTML table

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create an Angular pipe that filters out data. User types in a search query `municipality` and then the pipe should filter only those objects from an array that have a matching key value pair `municipality`.

I tried to create an `export` to `app.module.ts`, but that trick didn't work.

## app.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Automatic Teller Machines</h1>

  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="municipality" placeholder="Municipality">
    </div>
  </div>    

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Availability</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let atm of atms | search:municipality">
        <td>{{ atm.target_address }}, {{ atm.postalnumber }}
          {{ atm.municipality }}</td>
        <td>{{ atm.location }}, {{ atm.location_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ atm.availability }} {{ atm.availability_details }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>    
</div>
```

## app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ATMsService } from '../app/atms.service';

interface atm {
    target_address: string,
    postalnumber: string,
    municipality: string,
    location: string,
    location_type: string,
    availability: string,
    availability_details: string,
    coordinates_lat: string,
    coordinates_lon: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  municipality: string;
  atms: atm[] = [];

  constructor(public service: ATMsService) { }

  searchByMunicipalityName = (municipality: string) => {
    this.service.searchByMunicipalityName(municipality).then((data) => {
      this.atms = data;
    })
  }

}
```

## search.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

interface atm {
    target_address: string,
    postalnumber: string,
    municipality: string,
    location: string,
    location_type: string,
    availability: string,
    availability_details: string,
    coordinates_lat: string,
    coordinates_lon: string
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(atms: atm[], municipality: string): any {
    let filteredAtms: atm[] = [];

    if (municipality) {
      filteredAtms= atms.filter(o => o.municipality== municipality.toUpperCase());
    } else {
      filteredAtms= atms;
    }
    return filteredAtms;
  }

}

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OttoautomaatitService } from '../app/ottoautomaatit.service';
import { SivutusPipe } from './sivutus.pipe';
import { HakuPipe } from './haku.pipe';
```

## app.module.ts:

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SearchPipe
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule
      ],
      providers: [ATMsService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

I am expecting to be able to filter out data from a JSON file that contains an array of objects, but instead nothing happens when I type in a search query `municipality`. Where there should be an HTML table containing the final filtered data, nothing appears.

Comment: BTW, that's now the correct way to define an interface in TypeScript. It should be properties with a semicolon instead of commas next to its type.

Comment: And please consider following the [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) for [interfaces](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces).

Comment: This looks like you are perhaps attempting to make an api call each time the user types, since you are trying to pass the value user is typing to `seachByMunicipality` as a param to the api call. So which are you attempting to do, if this is not the case, then the below answer is correct, fetch all municipalities **once**, store it in an array and then filter it. But your question isn't really clear as to what exactly you are trying to do ;) At least not for me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you provided I get the idea that the function `searchByMunicipalityName` suppose to populate the `atms` array. But its never getting called anywhere. I speculate that if you change you **app component constructor** to

```
constructor(public service: ATMsService) {
    this.searchByMunicipalityName('');
}
```

might solve your problem.

Comment: I would suggest to make call in `OnInit` instead. Avoid doing such things in constructor :)

Comment: agree with @AJT_82